Lebesgue integral as a Summation like Riemann
I'm an IB student who currently just finished Math 31 HL (calculus grade 12). For an Internal assessment math paper I wanted to try and derive a formula that works like the Riemann summ but rather than partioning the domain I want to partition the range similar to how the Lebsuage integral works. Now I am not familiar with number theory, and real analysis but all I aim to is derive a simple or somewhat complex formula. Do you think that this is achievable with what I know, and if so would taking a graphical approach be more benfieical to writing the equation or finding patterns.

Do you want to define the Lebesgue integral as is usually done in a course on measure theory? Or do you simply want to define a different kind of Riemann integral that instead chops up the $y$-axis?

For the sake of the paper I aim to just define a different Rieman integral that chops the y axis, I would like to try the Lebsuage integral but honestly it looks quite hard. I may try to compare the derived formula with the lesbsuage integral and or Rieman and see how it holds up but also try some non Riemann integral functions to test the limits of the derived formula

The problem with chopping up the $y$-axis is that you then need to deal with measures of quite complicated sets on the $x$-axis. But your goal, I suppose, should be to interpret/understand why the area under $y=f(x)$ (with reasonable assumptions on $f$) is given by $\int_{\Bbb R} m({x: f(x)\ge y})dy$.

Thank you so much, I think I have obtained a general idea of where fo start, if it ever gets to hard I can always switch topics

Regarding the close votes (3 at the present time), although this question includes some OP-specific information, I think the essential question itself is sufficiently general to be useful for others, namely what are some reasonably elementary ideas and references for how domain partitioning differs from range partitioning in integration.

Perhaps consider restricting the functions to be continuous and monotonic?

Probably will do that, I am gonna make them simple since this task is difficult

I think trying to chop the $y$-axis, even using intervals, is going to involve more complicated sets than is handled by Riemann integration. Consider, for example, partitioning the $y$-axis into the intervals $\left[n - \frac{1}{2},\; n + \frac{1}{2}\right]$ (as $n$ varies over the integers) for the Dirichlet function. In fact, I believe using intervals for the range essentially gives you the Lebesgue integral, since Lebesgue measurability of a function is equivalent to the inverse image of intervals under that function being Lebesgue measurable sets.
Possibly useful is the Mathematics Stack Exchange question/answers How is Lebesgue integration "partitioning the range"? A nice expository treatment of many conceptual aspects of Lebesgue integration is given in Measure and the Integral by Lebesgue (1966 translation by Kenneth O. May), which -- if you don't want to purchase the book -- you might find be able to find at a nearby college/university library or obtain by interlibrary loan.
Something you might want to investigate instead of the range partitioning issue are various restrictions on Riemann integration and what effect they have on which functions are integrable. Restrictions such as, but not limited to: (A) Partitions using subintervals of the same length, but the point in each subinterval can be chosen arbitrarily. (B) Partitions using subintervals of the same length AND the point in each subinterval is chosen to be the left endpoint of that subinterval. Related to these ideas, see this 10 Dec 2002 sci.math post and its nearly immediate follow-up post, and this 7 Nov 2007 sci.math post, and the mathoverflow question Cauchy's left endpoint integral (1823).
Unfortunately, some background in undergraduate real analysis and writing proofs would probably be needed to do much with these ideas. Maybe look at Fermat's method of integrating certain functions using Riemann sums where the partition points form a geometric sequence (see here and this google search), and perhaps investigate the possibility of using other types of sequences in a similar way for certain other functions.
